# How to use callback in .then() function in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, callback

I have nodejs module to fetch data from mongodb database using mongodb driver. Callback is passed to given function which return a promise, but instead of returning result in .then() function, it is passing value to callback function. How can I call this function from other module or function since it is not returning it in .then()? I tried to console the result of .then(), but it is showing undefined.

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const Db = require('../model/db');

Db.findUser = (details, callback) => {
    return dbconnection().then(db => {
        if (db) {
          return db.collection('users').findOne({
            email: details.email,
            pass: details.password
          }).then(data => {
            if (data) {
              console.log('Found one');
              callback(true);
            } else {
              let err = new Error();
              callback(err);
            }
          })
        }
```

I have used following function to call the promise. I am new to promises.

```js
var getUser = function(callback) {
  db.findUser().then(result => {
    console.log(result) // undefined
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it using `async/await`. Something like this:

```
Db.findUser = async (details, callback) => {
  const db = await dbconnection();
  const data = await db.collection('users').findOne({
    email: details.email,
    pass: details.password
  });

  if (data) {
    console.log('Found one');
    callback(true);
  } else {
    let err = new Error();
    callback(err);
  }

  return data;
}
```

and consume it like:

```
const getUser = async (details, callback) => {
  const data = await Db.findUser();

  // do whatever you need with data  

  return data;  
}
```